# How to separate each blast result using python regex and store it in a list for further analysis

Tags: python, regex, bioinformatics, biopython

I am working on a set of biological sequences which involves the use of ncbi-blast. I need some help with processing the output file using python regex. The text result containing multiple outputs (sequence analysis results) looks something like this,

> **Query= lcl|TRINITY_DN2888_c0_g2_i1**
>
> Length=1394
>                                                                         Score     E Sequences producing significant alignments:
>   (Bits)  Value
>
> sp|Q9S775|PKL_ARATH
>
> CHD3-type chromatin-remodeling factor PICKLE...  1640    0.0
>
> sp|Q9S775|PKL_ARATH CHD3-type chromatin-remodeling factor PICKLE
>   OS=Arabidopsis thaliana  OX=3702 GN=PKL PE=1 SV=1 Length=1384
>
> Score = 1640 bits (4248),  Expect = 0.0, Method: Compositional matrix
>   adjust.  Identities = 830/1348 (62%), Positives = 1036/1348 (77%),
>   Gaps = 53/1348 (4%)
>
> Query  1
>   MSSLVERLRVRSERRPLYTDDDSDDDLYAARGGSESKQEERPPERIVRDDAKNDTCKTCG  60
>                MSSLVERLR+RS+R+P+Y  DDSDDD +  +     +Q     E IVR DAK + C+ CG Sbjct  1
>   MSSLVERLRIRSDRKPVYNLDDSDDDDFVPKKDRTFEQ----VEAIVRTDAKENACQACG  56
>
> Lambda      K        H        a         alpha
>      0.317    0.134    0.389    0.792     4.96
>
> Gapped Lambda      K        H        a         alpha    sigma
>      0.267   0.0410    0.140     1.90     42.6     43.6
>
> Effective search space used: 160862965056
>
> **Query= lcl|TRINITY_DN2855_c0_g1_i1**
>
> Length=145 ........................................
>   ...................................................
>   ...................................................

I want to extract the information starting from "***Query= lcl|TRINITY_DN2888_c0_g2_i1***" to the next query "***Query=lcl|TRINITY_DN2855_c0_g1_i1***" and store it in a python list for further analysis (since the entire file contains few thousands of query results). Is there a python regex code that can do this action?

Here is my code:

```
#!/user/bin/python3
file=open("path/file_name","r+")
import re
inter=file.read()
lst=[]
lst=re.findall(r'>(.*)>',inter,re.DOTALL)
print(lst)
for x in lst:
    print(x)
```

I get the wrong output since the code prints the entire information present in file (thousands) rather than picking up one result at a time.

Thank you

Comment: Hey @Jithin, you can probably do this in a simpler way. Will the breaking line always start with `Query=lcl|...`?

Comment: Also, do you want each chunk as a big string in the list? Or do you want more granularity than that?

Comment: The [split](https://linux.die.net/man/1/split) command might be useful here if you don't mind preprocessing your data.

Comment: Have you considered using an existing wrapper for NCBI BLAST query API? [biopython has this implemented](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Blast-module.html), for example. You should almost never need to roll your own parser in bioinformatics.

Comment: The breaking line always starts with "Query=lcl" and yes I want each chunk of data (each Query output) into list. Eg: lst=["Query 1 + data", "Query 2 + data", ....] as string. @ Mr Dolan , Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the result you want, edit the line with the `re.findall()` method call to the following using `re.split()`:

```
lst=re.split(r'(>Query\=.*)?',inter,re.DOTALL)
```

See this for more info on `re.split()`:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Also, you may want to consider using the now deprecated BLAST parser in `biopython`:

http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc96

> The plain text BLAST parser is located in Bio.Blast.NCBIStandalone.
>
> As with the XML parser, we need to have a handle object that we can
>   pass to the parser. The handle must implement the readline() method
>   and do this properly. The common ways to get such a handle are to
>   either use the provided blastall or blastpgp functions to run the
>   local blast, or to run a local blast via the command line, and then do
>   something like the following:
>
> > > result_handle = open("my_file_of_blast_output.txt")
>
> Well, now that we’ve got a handle (which we’ll call result_handle), we
>   are ready to parse it. This can be done with the following code:

```
>>> from Bio.Blast import NCBIStandalone
>>> blast_parser = NCBIStandalone.BlastParser()
>>> blast_record = blast_parser.parse(result_handle)
```

> This will parse the BLAST report into a Blast Record class (either a
>   Blast or a PSIBlast record, depending on what you are parsing) so that
>   you can extract the information from it. In our case, let’s just print
>   out a quick summary of all of the alignments greater than some
>   threshold value.

```
>>> E_VALUE_THRESH = 0.04
>>> for alignment in blast_record.alignments: 
...     for hsp in alignment.hsps: 
...         if hsp.expect < E_VALUE_THRESH: 
...             print('****Alignment****') 
...             print('sequence:', alignment.title) 
...             print('length:', alignment.length)
...             print('e value:', hsp.expect) 
...             print(hsp.query[0:75] + '...') 
...             print(hsp.match[0:75] + '...') 
...             print(hsp.sbjct[0:75] + '...')
```

> If you also read the section 7.3 on parsing BLAST XML output, you’ll
>   notice that the above code is identical to what is found in that
>   section. Once you parse something into a record class you can deal
>   with it independent of the format of the original BLAST info you were
>   parsing. Pretty snazzy!

Comment: I have worked with `from Bio.Blast import NCBIStandalone` biopython blast parser before. The output which I am working with right now was obtained from a tool that I used to obtain the 3'UTR regions form sequence. The reason why I am looking for handling each output with python regex is to obtain more insight on the result and do better analysis. Thank you @ Mr Vince

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the solution to break the huge file into small chunks so that I can process individual query result using python regex... Here is my code...

```
#!/user/bin/python3
file=open("/path/file_name.txt","r+")
import re
inter=file.read()
lst=re.findall('(?<=Query= lcl)(.*?)(?=Effective search space)', inter, flags=re.S)
print(lst)
```

Thank you all for helping me out...

Comment: Yes, using lookahead is the optimal solution. I just couldn't figure out the correct regex so used `re.split()`. Nice work!